# Case conversion from oozie workflow

Tags: workflow, oozie

I have an oozie workflow where, the input path has been stated as:

```
    <property>
      <name>inputDir</name>
        <value>dir.db/test_${personName}</value>
    </property>
```

The personName comes with upper case. Is there any way I can change it to lower case from this statement (inside the oozie workflow)?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that out of the box.

Oozie supports basic [JSP Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html), and defines [some custom methods](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions), but that's all -- it does not ship with the [JSTL utility methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) such as `fn:toLowerCase()`

But you can...

- define your own EL methods, using **custom Java code**
- declare these methods in the Oozie server configuration
- call these methods in your Workflow

You will find a tutorial about custom EL methods in that Cloudera blog post:
   *[How-to: Write an EL Function in Apache Oozie](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-write-an-el-function-in-apache-oozie/)*